# Web browser steam guard code issue

Tags: c#, browser, web, steam

I am making a web browser in C# and have noticed that when I go to steams website and try to login I get message asking for the steam guard code that was sent to my email.

I then go to my email, get the code and enter it but every time I get a message saying "Whoops! Sorry, that isn't quite right.".

I have tried copy and pasting and manually typing in the code to no avail.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Comment: No. We can't help you with such a broad, vague question. You're going to have to do more analysis for yourself. Download [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and take a look at the requests that are sent from your browser and compare with those sent from a standard browser, then ask a more specific question if those differences fail to make sense. I assume that you're embedding a browser control in your application, in which case, comparing requests against Internet Explorer's requests is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Does your browser handle cookies correctly? The moment you submit the code, the steam application creates a cookie. Maybe your browser rejects the cookie thus causing the error.